# catkin_package() include dir neither an absolute directory nor exists relative to workspace

Tags: ros, include, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to convert [camera1394](http://ros.org/wiki/camera1394) to catkin. My working repository is [this master branch](https://github.com/ros-drivers/camera1394).

Perhaps foolishly, I am attempting this migration by hand, using only the documentation I can find on-line. That has *not* been easy or pleasant, but I wanted to see if I could do it.

When trying to build by itself on Precise in a catkin workspace based on Groovy, I get this failure:

```
$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/joq/ros/hydro
Source space: /home/joq/ros/hydro/src
Build space: /home/joq/ros/hydro/build
Devel space: /home/joq/ros/hydro/devel
Install space: /home/joq/ros/hydro/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/joq/ros/hydro/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/joq/ros/hydro/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/joq/ros/hydro/install" in "/home/joq/ros/hydro/build"
####
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/joq/ros/hydro/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/groovy
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/groovy
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.3")
-- Looking for include files CMAKE_HAVE_PTHREAD_H
-- Looking for include files CMAKE_HAVE_PTHREAD_H - found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE 
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.63
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - camera1394
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'camera1394'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(camera1394)
-- Boost version: 1.46.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
-- checking for module 'libdc1394-2'
--   found libdc1394-2, version 2.2.0
-- dynamic_reconfigure built cfg/Camera1394.cfg: Generating reconfiguration files for Camera1394 in camera1394
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:266 (message):
  catkin_package() include dir '/home/joq/ros/hydro/devel/include' is neither
  an absolute directory nor exists relative to
  '/home/joq/ros/hydro/src/camera1394'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:78 (_catkin_package)
  camera1394/CMakeLists.txt:34 (catkin_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

I don't know how to set this. The **camera1394** package has no **include/** subdirectory, since it exports no header files. I've tried many different ideas, but really have no clear concept what this message is complaining about.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55456/catkin_package()-include-dir-neither-an-absolute-directory-nor-exists-relative-to-workspace/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2013-02-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This particular message seems to come from dynamic_reconfigure generation.

The fix is to [change the cfg file](http://www.ros.org/wiki/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/HowToWriteYourFirstCfgFile#dynamic_reconfigure.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-HowToWriteYourFirstCfgFile.2BAC8-rosbuild.The_cfg_File). In place of:

```
from dynamic_reconfigure.parameter_generator import *
```

catkin packages should use:

```
from dynamic_reconfigure.parameter_generator_catkin import *
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asfandyar Ashraf Malik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5044/asfandyar-ashraf-malik/) on 2013-06-17**:
Hello, I have encountered a similar problem. Can you indicate to me how can I access the cfg files. There are many cfg files.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-06-17**:
Hard to answer that without more information. Would you please open a new question (which can link to this one) and provide details about the cfg files causing you trouble?

**Comment by [Asfandyar Ashraf Malik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5044/asfandyar-ashraf-malik/) on 2013-06-17**:
Thanks joq. I fixed the error. I just made an include folder inside src and did the catkin_make and it compiled. I asked this questions originally on this page with the specifications (http://answers.ros.org/question/65285/rviz-tutorial-error-dir-include-is-neither-an-absolute-directory-nor-exists/